# Hardware keyboard functions differently when the virtual keyboard is on or off - Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have a layout with multiple `TextInputEditText` stacked vertically. For the app's workflow I need that whenever an input gains focus, either by the user tapping on it or after pressing enter on a preceding input box, the contents should be automatically selected.

When using the virtual keyboard (either gboard or the device specific one), pressing enter on a field that has some text selected, simply moves the cursor to the next available input field leaving the text in place. Testing with a bluetooth keyboard shows the same behaviour while the virtual keyboard is enabled.

The problem arises when the virtual keyboard is hidden. Since the app is intended to be used with a hardware keyboard, it is a requirement to have the virtual keyboard hidden. However, if the virtual keyboard is hidden, pressing enter deletes the currently selected text before moving onto the next available input. The behaviour disappears when enabling the virtual keyboard again and viceversa. I need the selected text to stay in the box.

I thought maybe I made a mistake using `dispatchKeyEvent` or the `onKeyListeners` but even after commenting all of those out that undesired behaviour remains. Trying to look for selected text doesn't work as the system seems to delete text before passing the `KeyEvent` to the `onKeyListener`.

Is there a way to get the hardware keyboard to act as it does when the soft keyboard is enabled regardless of the state of the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different approaches I ended up creating a custom `TextInputEditText` and editing the `onKeyPreIme` to handle the Enter key presses before they are passed around by the OS.

From what I found in debugging the events move like this
`onKeyPreIme > onKeyListener > dispatchKeyEvent`, with probably more things in between but this is what was relevant to this case.

Since the navigation flow is specified by `onKeyPreIme` I stopped using `onKeyListener` and moved the logic to `onFocusChangeListener`.